# Login to a RESTful Rails app with HTTParty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, devise, signing, httparty

I have a web app with a clean RESTful JSON API, based on **Rails 3.2**, **Ruby 1.9** and **Devise 2**.

I would like to write a small script based on **HTTParty** web client in order to perform some actions frequently (with a crontab). But how can we **sign in** and keep the session open (with the session id passed by HTTP HEADER, and maybe stored in a cookie).

I really have no experience about this aspect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this mailing list comment as of January, may not be possible:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/httparty-gem/cookie/httparty-gem/H2me9zB1mEI/RNy3pdSzWnsJ

I personally started a project with HTTParty, and moved to RestClient because the behavior seems was more straightforward IMHO.  Checkout the 'cookies' section of:

https://github.com/archiloque/rest-client

...may suite your needs.

Justin

Comment: [This is](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client) the new url for rest-client